# unexpected value C structure

Tags: c, struct, char, int

I'm looking for some help with understanding why I'm getting a value. I've got a very basic menu to select and set values on a KL25Z micro controller (32-bit architecture). I've got an int that wont print a value above 255. What am I doing wrong?

beacon.h

```
typedef struct _payload_t {

int t1_range;

} PAYLOAD_T;
```

beacon.c

```
#define BUFFSIZE 100
PAYLOAD_T payload;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

char line[2];
int ret, select;

// print menu
print_menu();

// get menu input
ret = readline(line, BUFFSIZE, stdin, stdout);

select = atoi(line);

switch(select)
{

case 1:

uprintf(" Target 1 Starting Range: ");
ret = readline(line, BUFFSIZE, stdin, stdout); //--> 257
payload.t1_range = atoi(line);
printf(" Selection = %s\r\n", line); //--> 257
printf("(%d)\r\n",payload.t1_range); //--> 1
break;

... rest of case
}
return 0;
} //end main
```

Everything works ok until values above 255 are entered, then the values displayed seem to revert back to 1. If payload.t1_range is an int (16 bits) why is it acting like an 8 bit?

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is an accurate representation of your code? One `BUFFSIZE` has two F's.

Comment: Agreed; please post **real** code.

Comment: The keyword closest to `typdef` is `typedef`.  Also, your `line` is a **two** element array of char (irrespective of what `BUFFSIZE` or `BUFSIZE` might be).

Comment: You declare line as a 2-character array and input 3-digit numbers?

Comment: 1 million dollar question: you are reading a simple number, why can't you use a stupid `scanf("%d", &(payload.t1_range));`

Comment: @Rob013 I don't think we need to use this kind of tone here!

Comment: As Jim suggested, it's generally better to use a `BUFSIZE` of 100 only when you have a buffer with at least 100 elements in it, rather than 2.

Comment: @Qwerty I didn't mean to be rude, I'm sorry for that. I was suggesting to not increase code complexity and find the simpliest solution.

Comment: @Rob013 - I'm working with a bare metal setup, using a "stupid scanf" doesn't echo stdin to the correct uart by default so unfortunately it's not that simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line` is 2 chars long. `atoi` works on nul terminated strings, so anything over a 1 character number is going to give you undefined behavior.

Try making `line` bigger.

Comment: Thanks John for the useful advice and looking past a couple of typos. Seems like some of the other's had a rough day or in the process of trying to make a diamond out of coal. Thanks again.

Comment: What fixed the problem - since my max value would be 2 bytes I increased line to "char line[3]" then performed "memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));" to zero out the bits so I didn't have to worry about atoi not hitting a null. Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: @txcotrader `line[3]` still won't handle the value 256 - you've used all your chars with no room for a nul terminator.